# Fake, Heatless Sun-like object hovering over a person on Earth, how deadly it would be?

Tags: environment, earth-like, habitability

Above the Crimson King in my story is a sun-like paetheon-sized asteroid (5.8 km in diameter) that follows him and never sets.
This is not an asteroid actually but i call it false sun and it appears crimson red, it is covered in blood, but it only emits light, because the real sun shines upon it. The more the sun falls on it, the more visible it shines. And it radiates no heat, like real sun.

The power of this sun is to turn every human it sees into molten flesh monsters. There is no scientific explanation for its power. We can think of it as some kind of cursed object.
We can think of the sun at the time of the eclipse as an image.

- If there were such a false sun on Earth and the sun would follow the Crimson King wherever he went, to what extent should the power of this false sun be so that it would not affect the whole world and affect only certain places?
- As an example, let's assume that such a false sun appears over Paris. From where could this sun be seen the farthest? So, would there be any difference in the transformation levels of people who see this sun according to the distance, just like how equator and north pole gets different sun levels?

Hello, I'm asking a lot of questions, but I don't know if my questions are off-topic, I only got a warning that says "I ask too much question." in the comments until now. If they look off-topic, please remove them if it's appropriate.

Comment: At what altitude is this object? If it's like most other celestial bodies, half the planet at a time can see it. It'll be visible from a smaller area the closer it is to the surface.

Comment: I thought if it were over 100 meters or so of him it would sound reasonable, but i suppose it wouldn't work. Maybe i should make it something similar to a halo, just behind him.

Comment: If it is giving off light it is giving off heat.

Comment: The language is unclear - do you mean "every human who sees it", or "every human the orb perceives"?  If the former, presumably people could Perseus the thing with a mirror or something.  If the latter, how far can the orb "see", can humans hide from it, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume that the Crimson King wears his glowy red ball like a hat or an elaborate do.  It is right on top of his head.  For calculations we will make the King himself of negligible height which might be why he feels the need for such a large hat/ elaborate do.

How far away is the horizon from 5800 meters up?

I used this website.
http://www.ringbell.co.uk/info/hdist.htm

and got a distance of **272.1 km.**  If you were that far up, that is where the horizon would be - the farthest you can see.  And so vice versa - persons 272 km away would see the red top of this ball just poking up.  Too bad for them!  It is lucky for us Yanks that the King must be in Europe or someplace they have kilometers because that is a big zone of molten flesh monsters.

You could make this more reasonable as regards monster zone by making it less big.  Perhaps the size of a red yoga ball.  Or a medium sized building?  Then you could not see it from so far away.  Or maybe it just makes some people into monsters and gives the others a rash.

It would work best out on the salt flats. The thing about Paris is that it is quite crammed with buildings, most of which provide shade and obscure the horizon.  Not the Eiffel tower; it has many holes.  So your chance of monsterification would depend on if you were outside, how close to a building you were, building height and other individual specific variables independent of the height and distance of the King and his ball.

Comment: I suppose i should make my bleeding ball around a medium sized building, that sounds more reasonable actually. Also having other side effects could be more effective to the people far away from it, i don't want to make them go mad from revelation, but something similar to rash or smallpox that gives something similar to skin cancer.

Comment: Maybe at a distance something good could happen, like hair becomes glossy and lush.  Then people would be coming to experience the good thing, but trying not to get too close.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the asteroid is at head height, you can calculate [from this](http://www.ringbell.co.uk/info/hdist.htm) the range is 272 kilometers. France is about [1000 kilometers wide](https://www.nationsencyclopedia.com/Europe/France-LOCATION-SIZE-AND-EXTENT.html), so about half of France would die as they became flesh monsters if it appeared above Paris.

The sun radiates massive amounts of heat (hence why the the Earth is warm), so scientifically the red sun is a bit weird.

You should limit the effect to those who are directly under the asteroid, or the Crimson King would very quickly become an extinction level event. Even with that, all of Paris would be twisted, but at least some would live.

Comment: It's odd that both you and Willk get 272, but one gets miles and the other km.